# Repeating level 0 multiindexing column header

Tags: python, pandas, header

I've a dataframe like this:

```
  AA BB  CC
0  a  b  c1
1  a  b  c2
2  a  b  c3
```

I want that to be multiindexed as this:

```
   A  A   A
  AA BB  CC
0  a  b  c1
1  a  b  c2
2  a  b  c3
```

Here is the code snippet that I was working on:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["AA", "BB", "CC"])
df.loc[0]= ["a", "b", "c1"]
df.loc[1]= ["a", "b", "c2"]
df.loc[2]= ["a", "b", "c3"]

header = 'A'
column_header = [header] * 3
tup = zip(column_header, df.columns)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tup)
print df
```

This is producing this output:

```
   A       
  AA BB  CC
0  a  b  c1
1  a  b  c2
2  a  b  c3
```

Can anyone please help to get my desired output? Can't find any solution that repeats 'A' multiple time in top level header.

Comment: Thank you Zero, but that produces the top header as A B C instead A A A.

Comment: Could not find any solution so far. Thanks for marking it as duplicate.